# Does the Vatican City/Holy See have a form of Security Clearance?

Tags: vatican-city

As far as I know, every sovereign nation has a form of security clearance to deal with matters of their national security. If you do a quick search of this topic you will find [a link](https://www.clearancejobs.com/jobs/holy-see-vatican-city-state) about security clearance jobs, but it does not mention having a Vatican City clearance.

Given that the Vatican City is a sovereign nation, do they have a security clearance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Vatican is not a typical nation.

There are about 600 "citizens". Each one is a member of the clergy (or in the Swiss Guard, plus a few nuns etc) and so 99% male and 100% catholic) and works in the governance of the Catholic church. So every single citizen has security clearance (at some level)

Citizenship is based entirely on appointment to a high ranking position in the clergy. The entire population is celibate and there are 0 natural-born citizens.

The systems such as "security clearance" needed in a state with a population of millions don't apply to the Vatican City.

This doesn't mean that the Vatican has no secrets...

Comment: "So every single citizen has security clearance (at some level)." This may sound like splitting hairs, but you seem to describe a de facto situation as opposed to a de jure policy.  Is this the case de jure?

Comment: The entire population is celibate, or the entire citizenry?

Comment: citizenry... but the general point remains.  The vatican is not a regular "state".  It is the only state with more than 1 pope per square km, for example